# Bounding a polynomial from below

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, polynomials, special-functions

Let $\sigma >0$ be fixed. For even $k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$, we consider the polynomial
\begin{equation}
\varphi_k(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^j {k \choose j} b_j \, x^{2j} \quad x \in (-1,1),
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
b_j = \frac{\Big(k+\sigma+\frac12\Big)_j}{\Big(\frac12 \Big)_j}
\end{equation}
and for $s \in \mathbb{R}$, $(s)_j$ denotes the Pochhammer symbol
\begin{equation}
(s)_{j}={\begin{cases}1&j=0\\s(s+1)\cdots (s+j-1)&j>0.\end{cases}}
\end{equation}
In particular, $\varphi_0(x) =1$.

My question is the following.

> *For $-1 < a < b < 1$, does there exist $c = c(a, b, \sigma)>0$ such that*
>   \begin{equation}
> \int_a^b \varphi_k(x)^2 dx \geq c \quad
> \end{equation}
>   *for any even $k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$?*

Unless I am mistaken, a straightforward computation yields
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b \varphi_k(x)^2 dx = \sum_{j=0}^k \sum_{\ell=0}^k (-1)^{j+\ell} {k \choose j} {k \choose \ell} \frac{b_j b_{\ell}}{2(j+\ell)+1} \, (b^{2(j+\ell)+1}-a^{2(j+\ell)+1}).
\end{equation}
But I do not see how I may bound this double sum from below.

**Remark 1:** I dont know if it is of any use, one may notice that $\varphi_k$ is a hypergeometric function of the form ${}_{2}F_{1}(-k,k+\sigma+\frac12;\frac12;x^2)$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

**Remark 2:** Using this interpretation as a hypergeometric function (which terminates), it is in fact possible to relate $\varphi_k$ to the *Jacobi polynomials* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_polynomials): 
\begin{equation}
\varphi_k(x) = {}_{2}F_{1}(-k,\sigma +\frac12 +k;\frac12; x^2)={\frac {k!}{(\alpha +1)_{k}}}P_{k}^{(-\frac12 ,\sigma )}(1-2x^2).
\end{equation}
Perhaps this observation may be of use.

*Comment*: *The same question is open for any odd $k \in \mathbb{N}$, but this time one considers*
\begin{equation}
\varphi_k(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^j {k \choose j} c_j \, x^{2j+1},
\end{equation}
*with* $
c_j = \frac{\Big(k+\sigma+\frac32\Big)_j}{\Big(\frac32 \Big)_j} $.
*I suspect that the methodology is similar as for the case where $k$ is even.*

Comment: Is c allowed to depend on k,a,$\sigma$ and b?

Comment: @ChocolateRain Not on $k$, as stated.

Comment: @ChocolateRain Thanks for pointing that out, you are right. I will edit my post.

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/326000/lower-bound-for-the-l2-norm-of-a-polynomial

Comment: Why do you write $|\varphi_k(x)|^2$ instead of $\varphi_k(x)^2$ since all numbers are real? Also, for $k=0$ we know $\varphi_0(x)=1$ and thus the integral is $b-a$ whose only lower bound is $c=0$ unless $c$ is **allowed** to depend on $a,b$.

Comment: @Somos The lower bound $c$ is allowed (and in fact **expected**) to depend on $a, b, \sigma$. I only want it to be uniform in $k$. This is insinuated in the statement of my question. As for the absolute value, you are right. I use this notation for consistency, as sometimes I work in higher dimensions. I have edited the question to be more precise.

Comment: I guess that [asymptotics of Jacobi polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_polynomials#Asymptotics_of_Jacobi_polynomials) can be helpful. Also computer calculations of the integrals for different $a$, $b$, $\sigma$ and $k$ tending to infinity still can provide some suggestions.