# Definite integral of a hypergeometric function

Tags: polynomials, definite-integrals, special-functions

This question is related to [Bounding a polynomial from below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3154394/bounding-a-polynomial-from-below) but perhaps more straightforward.

Let $\sigma >0$ be fixed. For even $k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$, we consider the hypergeometric function
\begin{equation}
\varphi_k(x) = {}_{2}F_{1}(-k,k+\sigma+\frac12;\frac12;x^2), \quad x \in (-1,1).
\end{equation}

My question is the following:

> Can we find a "closed form" for the definite integral 
>   \begin{equation}
> \int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^\sigma \varphi_k(x)^2 dx
> \end{equation}
>   for all even $k\in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$?

---

**Some remarks:**

Since $k$ is an integer, $\varphi_k$ terminates and is thus a polynomial of the form
\begin{equation}
\varphi_k(x) = \sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^j {k \choose j} b_j \, x^{2j} \quad x \in (-1,1),
\end{equation}
where 
$b_j = \frac{\Big(k+\sigma+\frac12\Big)_j}{\Big(\frac12 \Big)_j}$
and for $s \in \mathbb{R}$, $(s)_j$ denotes the Pochhammer symbol
\begin{equation}
(s)_{j}={\begin{cases}1&j=0\\s(s+1)\cdots (s+j-1)&j>0.\end{cases}}
\end{equation}
In particular, $\varphi_0(x) =1$.

Writing the square of the sum as the double sum of the product of the coefficients, and using the linearity of the integral, I obtain something of the form
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=0}^k \sum_{\ell = 0}^k (-1)^{j+\ell} {k \choose \ell} {k \choose j} \frac{b_j b_\ell}{2(j+\ell)+1} \int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^\sigma x^{2(\ell+j)} dx.
\end{equation}
Moreover, according to Wolfram Alpha, 
\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^\sigma x^{2(\ell+j)} dx = \frac{\Gamma(j+\ell+\frac12)\Gamma(\sigma+1)}{\Gamma(\sigma+\ell+j+\frac32)}.
\end{equation}
I am interested however in knowing if this can be reduced to an expression which does not contain a double sum and is more "compact".

I made this remark in the previous question, and perhaps they might be useful.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I'd note that
$$ (1-x^2)^\sigma \phi_k(x) = \,_2F_1(-k-\sigma,k+\frac12;\frac12;x^2)$$
That may be useful.